# Include API call inside a page to load lazy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api

I am calling an API to another service on this "form" page.

Most of the time the API call to the other service is slow.. and it takes 2-4 refreshes of the browser to complete the call.

My problem is:

I have a dropdown select menu populating from the API call:

> ```
>       <select name="memberID" id="memberID">
>            <?
>              if(!empty($organization_list))
>            {
>                foreach($organization_list as $memberID=>$companyName)
>                {
>
>                  $s = "";
>                  if($offer['memberID'] == $memberID || $_GET['m'] == $memberID) $s = " selected";
>                  echo "<option value='".$memberID."' $s>".stripslashes($companyName)."</option>";
>
>                }
>               }
>            ?> 
>           </select>
> ```

And obviously including the API function above..

Since this is the only SELECT / DROPDOWNN menu on the page that call from another API Service, it loads the first 2-3 times empty...

Is there a way I can have this select menu keep loading until fully finished while everything else on the page has loaded...

I don't want the entire page to be stalled because of this dropdown... ?

Thanks in advance NINJAS!!

Here is the API call :

> ini_set ('max_execution_time', 3000); 
>   {     print_r("
>
> ```
> ");   print_r($data); }
> ```
>
> define("API_KEY",'XXX'); define("ACCOUNT_ID",'XXX');
>
> /**
> ** This method is used for the get company list or contact or member 
> ** Param
> */  function get_organization_list() {    $api_key = API_KEY;     $account_id = ACCOUNT_ID;       $organization_list = array();
>
> ```
>   $url =
> ```
>
> "https://api.wildapricot.org/v1/Accounts/$account_id/Contacts?apikey=$api_key";
>     $public_contact_member  = file_get_contents($url);
>                 $json_decode_arr = json_decode($public_contact_member);         //pr($json_decode_arr);
>             if(!empty($json_decode_arr))    {        $json_decode_arr->ResultUrl;
>                 $url = '';      $url = $json_decode_arr->ResultUrl;         $url = $url."&apikey=".$api_key;
>                  $public_contact_member_list  = file_get_contents($url);
>                  $json_decode_arr = json_decode($public_contact_member_list);
>                  $json_decode_arr = ( array ) $json_decode_arr ;
>                     //pr($json_decode_arr);
>                 // Contacts         // $json_decode_arr["Contacts"];
>                 if( isset($json_decode_arr["Contacts"]) and !empty($json_decode_arr["Contacts"]) and
>   !isset($_SESSION["json_decode_arr"]))         {
>              $_SESSION["json_decode_arr"] = $json_decode_arr;       }
>                 if(isset($_SESSION["json_decode_arr"]) and !empty($_SESSION["json_decode_arr"]))        {
>              $json_decode_arr = $_SESSION["json_decode_arr"] ;
>                         // pr($_SESSION["json_decode_arr"]);        }
>                 if(!empty($json_decode_arr["Contacts"]))        { 
>              $size_of_array = count($json_decode_arr["Contacts"]);
>                         for($i=0;$i
>                     $array_field = (array)  $json_decode_arr["Contacts"][$i]->FieldValues;
>                 //  pr( $array_field );
>
> `$value_get = 16;
>            $orgranization_id = $array_field[$value_get]->Value;
>
>            $value_get = 17;
>            $orgranization_name = $array_field[$value_get]->Value;
>
>           if($orgranization_name!="")
>           {
>
>             $member_id='';
>
>               for($jk=0; $jk<count($array_field); $jk++)
>               {
>                   if($member_id=="")
>                   {
>                       $filed_name = $array_field[$jk]->FieldName;
>                       if($filed_name=="Member ID")
>                       {
>                            $member_id = $array_field[$jk]->Value;
>                           //echo '<br/>';
>                       }
>                   }
>               }
>
>
>               if(isset($member_id) and $member_id!='')
>               {
>                   $organization_list[$member_id] = $orgranization_name;
>
>               }else{
>
>                   $organization_list[$orgranization_id] = $orgranization_name;
>
>               }
>           }
>
>                       }       }
>
>           }
>       asort($organization_list);      return $organization_list;`
>
> }

Comment: could you format you're code so it is readable and remove part that are not releavant for you're problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You should considere using XMLHttpRequest (ajax)

for example with php and jquery

```
<?php
//getMyDropdown.php
$item1 = array(
    "id"=>1,
    "description"=>"fu"
);
$item2 = array(
    "id"=>2,
    "description"=>"bar"
);
$output = [$item1,$item2]:
echo json_encode($output);
exit();
?>
<form action="http://mysite.fr/action.php" method="post">
    <select id="myDropdown"></select>
    <input type="submit" value="send" disabled/>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/getMyDropdown.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function ( data ) {
            var select = document.getElementById('myDropdown'), html = "";
            for(var i = 0, max = data.length; i < max; i++){
                html += "<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].description + "</option>\n";
            }
            select.innerHTML = html;
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

    </script>
```

Could you add a sample of code so we can adapt our answer ?

Comment: the api call actually used "ajax", so not sure where to begin?

Comment: You say "it takes 2-4 refreshes of the browser to complete the call.", what do you mean refreshes ?

Comment: hard browser refreshes to populate the "select menu" with the company names that I am retrieving from the API call

Comment: That sounds like the api call fails 2-3 times before you get the data to populate the select element?

Comment: hard browser ? I think you're javascript code is refreshing the whole page.
The right way is to request with an ajax call datas from the server, and when you get you're answer, populate you're select.

You should not touch the GUI, and if you're form isn't ready to be posted until data's are there, you should disable the form submission until you get the ajax response.

Comment: it times out. here is what their engineers say: API is asynchronous. This means when a call is executed a results ticket is created and those results are not instantly formed as it takes some time for API server to process a request. The ticket with an id is stored for 5 minutes. This means all requests with same API call and parameters will be assigned to that already created ticket.
This is the main reason when sometimes you do not see the list with results - a request is being processed and no results are available.

Comment: you can see above in the question! THanks!

Comment: So i might be able to try your code above and just rename my include code to "getMyDropdown.php" ?

Comment: This is a very basic example, if you adapt you're code, you could serialize any kind of object, so yes it will work

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ajax and js frameworks like jQuery with it's [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) methods.

Comment: so I can wrap this "select menu" into another ajax call ?

Comment: Ajax calls are normal HTTP requests done by JavaScript, in addition you can use the data returned by the request and populate dropdowns for instance. In case you do not know the concept yet, you now have a search keyword ;)

Comment: thanks, i understand the concept. just hoping I can get it to work the the API Ajax call ?